# wget doesn't seem to download icons from a webpage

Tags: wget

I want to download webpages for offline viewing. In particular, I want to download this webpage: [The Leibniz entry on SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/leibniz/), so I run the following in my terminal

`wget -p -np https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/leibniz/`

which is supposed to download the images, etc. needed to display the webpage, but without ascending to the parent directory.

However, some icons on the webpage are missing when I open the downloaded webpage. To be specific, the pictures below show some of the icons missing in the the downloaded webpage. (I get the same result from different browsers)

This is the top left of the original webpage:

[image: original webpage]

and this is the top left of the downloaded webpage:

[image: downloaded webpage]

I have figured out that all the icons that are missing are from a font called ["Font Awesome"](https://fontawesome.com/icons). When `wget` download the webpage it does provide me with a subdirectory called "font" which contains files with names containing the string "fontawesome", so `wget` does recognise that the webpage uses this font somehow.

**Does anyone know why the icons doesn't show in the downloaded webpage?**

Comment: I don't suppose the images are in a parent directory?

Comment: I get the same result without the -np flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that `wget` saves font name with full query string, so you've got `fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1`

On the other hand browser, when making request throws off query string part (`?v=3.2.1`) and tries to request only `fontawesome-webfont.ttf`.

TBH I don't know "who is to blame" - wget or browser.

You can fix those icons by simply making link of `fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.2.1` file as `fontawesome-webfont.ttf`.

This is not new problem. Somebody else encountered this scenario https://gist.github.com/pigeonflight/f8d5d6efbadf8cb341d6a44d17de3d59 (funny - it is the same font!).

Mine solution for this problem is to avoid unix file naming schema by using option `--restrict-file-names=windows`. This forces wget to use, among many others things (see manual), `@` mark instead of `?` which does job right.